# How to run PHP script in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, php, html, firebase

I am working on Firebase web Javascript but inside my project I want to run one PHP script, but I don't know how to run this script.

```
HTML

<form method="POST" action="./abcd.php">
   <input type="email" id="mc-email" name="mc-email" required/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

PHP Script

<?php
   echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Please kindly go through my above post and let me know how to run PHP script inside my firebase web project.

Answer (score 3):

The question is old but for new guys dealing with firebase; regarding to current docs firebase is static assets only. You can still use its realtime db, storage and auth like other helper functions and scale your project if these kind of features are okay for you.

If one want to execute some server code such as PHP,Java,.Net,Go,NodeJS google has cloud solution support these languages
https://cloud.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the rest api of Firebase. 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html
https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

Comment: hey thanks but when i am doing form action it downloading that php file

Comment: @MyChat check the starting of your php code, must start with <?php